# Different amount at different prices = aggregate price

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 100 units at 1.00$ each and 200 units at 0.50$ each.
I would like to know the excel formula to aggregate the unit price of all my units.
The result should be 0.67$ (rounded up)

I tried a formula like:

> =SUM(100*1+200*0.5)/300

or

> =SUM(A2*B2+A3*B3)/SUM(A2:A3)

[image]

This formula works (even if it's primal) for few different amount/prices but I'm looking for something more clean at larger scale. (e.g. 200+ different entries)

I also tried the function AGGREGATE but not sure how to use it correctly for my use case.

In big picture, I need to calculate my unit price even if I bought different amount at different price. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A7,B2:B7)/SUM(B2:B7)
```

Comment: Even if it's the same product in my use case, this solution is clean and works =)

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(A2:A7,B2:B7)/SUM(A2:A7)  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try productsum.
It's like a conditional multiplication of numbers.

[image]

Formulas:

```
F4: =SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$9=E4)*$B$2:$B$9*$C$2:$C$9)
F5: =SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$9=E5)*$B$2:$B$9*$C$2:$C$9)
F6: =SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$9=E6)*$B$2:$B$9*$C$2:$C$9)
```

and then there is a normal =Sum below.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i'm looking for average unit price instead total price.
I'll edit my first post with an example